# How to use global or shared styles between components in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

In **ionic 3** we use `app.scss` file to write global styles. **Ionic 4** is not providing a scss variable to override `ion-inputs` background as well as many other css properties.

I need to apply a white background to all the `ion-inputs`. For now, I was able to do it by replicating the following scss code on each component:

```
:host { 
  ion-input {
    --background: white;
  }
}
```

But I would like to write this code in only one place.
What is the scss file to do it? Do I have to import that file in some place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to put your css in **variable.scss** like this

```
ion-input {
  background-color: white;
}
```

then whenever you are using `ion-input` it takes background color **white**.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the custom styles in **styles.scss**, but remind that if they are intermediate stylesheets, you must add `!important` to ensure:

```
ion-input {
   --background: var(--ion-color-light) !important;
}
```

**Note:** Use `var(--ion-color-light)` to apply Ionic native light (white) color from **variables.scss**.

Comment: It's not so welcome method to make too many use of `!important`.

Comment: @AliD. I know, but I think that his use is accepted when you use in a global styles file, for avoiding intermediate style declarations or `inherit` in all child classes.

Comment: Maybe. But there's an **accepted** answer above which might be more agreeable.